# OpenWeatherMap returning wrong results

Tags: javascript, ajax, api

I am getting wrong information from openweathermap.org. 
It is returning the information that is being displayed in the examples given on the website.

Here's my **HTML** code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Your Weather</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
        <h1>The Weather</h1>
            <div>
                <p>
                    <span id="show-weather"></span>
                    <span id="show-country"></span>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="custom.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here's my **JS** code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
            id: '2172797',
            appid: 'b1b15e88fa797225412429c1c50c122a1'
        },
        url: 'https://openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather/',
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: false
        },
        headers: {},
        success: function(data) {

            $("#show-weather").text("Your location latitude is: " + data.coord.lat + " and longitude is: " + data.coord.lon);
            $("#show-country").text(" Your current location is: " + data.sys.name);

        },
        error: function(data) {

            console.log('error');
            console.log(data);
        },
    });
});
```

I am unable to get the current information like city name or latitude or longitude.

Comment: What does the response look like?  Are you getting errors in your console?

Answer (score 0):

The name property is at the root Level so you need to use the `data.name` property and if you need the country name then the value should be `data.sys.country`. There is no property named `name` under `data.sys`

**Complete working code:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
            id: '2172797',
            appid: 'b1b15e88fa797225412429c1c50c122a1'
        },
        url: 'https://openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather/',
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: false
        },
        headers: {},
        success: function(data) {
//console.log(data);
            $("#show-weather").text("Your location latitude is: " + data.coord.lat + " and longitude is: " + data.coord.lon);
            $("#show-country").text(" Your current location is: " + data.sys.country);

        },
        error: function(data) {

            console.log('error');
            console.log(data);
        },
    });
});
```

```html
  <body>
        <div>
        <h1>The Weather</h1>
            <div>
                <p>
                    <span id="show-weather"></span>
                    <span id="show-country"></span>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The id query parameter you are sending with the request is a city id... the same id used in the api docs examples. Change the id or check out the docs on how to query other cities using other query params.